# pipe in Solaris terminal doesn't work?

Tags: solaris, pipe

It should be a very easy question for any Solaris Admin

It seems that I can't pipe result from one command to another, for example,

ipadm | more

is not working, it still shows the entire result without paging it nicely
I sure I forgot something, but What?

I'm using Solaris 11 in VMWARE

Answer (score 2):

ipadm prints its output to stderr, not so stdout.

Use `ipadm 2>&1 | more` or a similar construct.

Comment: It Works but could you use one line tell me what is 2>&1 ?

Comment: `2>&1` redirects file descriptor 2 to be a copy of file descriptor 1. FD 1 is standard out, and FD 2 is standard error. The effect is to make the process's standard error go to the same place as its standard out.